# How to copy fetched documents from Firestore to local array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a collection in Firebase from which I fetch all documents. I'd like to copy all those docs inside an array/ArrayList and display them on screen. I looked at questions tagged as duplicate already but everytime people used FirestoreFirebase and I'm using AngularFirestore. I'm successfully retrieving docs and displaying them in the console, but I really can't seem to copy them inside an array.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

    export interface Book { title: string; writer: string; }

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-books',
    templateUrl: './books.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
    })

    export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

    public books: Book[] = [];
    public book: Book = {title: 'dummy', writer: 'dummy'}

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.db.collection('books').get().subscribe(function(querySnapshot) {
         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            // TODO: pass docs data to books array defined above
            // Already tried to execute code below, I get "This is not defined" error
            // this.book.title = doc.get('title');
            // this.book.writer= doc.get('writer');
            // this.books.push(this.book);
         });
      });
     }
    }
```

Here the method is to retrieve them one by one, and I'm trying to write inside the array as I'm retrieving the docs. But in the end as long as I can put all docs inside and array I wouldn't mind retrieving all documents and then only pushing them. I really can't seem to solve this one.

Comment: I marked the duplicate with the assumption that you're just asking why you get a "this not defined" error in the code you have commented out.  You'll need to change the way you declare your callback function.  If you have an additional question, please post it separately.